# What files do you typically put in .dockerignore

Tags: docker, containers

I am building a Django application with docker.
I would like to know for Django or general development work using docker, what files are typically included in the .dockerignore.
I am thinking of the following for now:

- .git
- *.pyc

Answer (score 5):

You may have noticed that if you put a Dockerfile in your home, and launch a `docker build` you will see a message `uploading context`, this means docker creates a .tar with all the files in your home and in all the subdirectories, and uploads this tar to the docker daemon.

If you have some huge files, this may take a long time.

So to avoid this you may

1) create a specific directory, where you put your Dockerfile, and all what is needed for your build

2) tell docker to ignore some files during the build

So you may put in the .dockerignore all the files not needed for your build

Comment: Thanks, I knew the concept of why .dockerignore is needed. But I was actually asking for more specefic suggestions for what type of files one usually put in .dockerignore (such as those I listed in the question).

Comment: I guess `.git
.gitignore
LICENSE
VERSION *.pyc
*/*.pyc
*/*/*.pyc
README.md
Changelog.md
Makefile`

Answer (score 2):

This what I typically put in .dockerignore for dockerized Django apps

```
**/*.pyc
**/*.pyo
**/*.mo
.gitignore
.git/
**/__pycache__/
Dockerfile
db.sqlite3
**/*.md
```

Comment: Thank you so much. These particular commands reduced my Django app size from 500MB to 347 MB